# Why this stack smashing?

Tags: c, debugging, stack-overflow

I got the following code(part of a `log` function):

```
/* set to 32 on purpose */
#define MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ 32

void log(const char *fmt, ...) {
    ....

    char msg[MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ] = {0};
    int nb_bytes = 0;

    /* get current time */
    time_t now = time(NULL);

    char time_buf[32] = {0};

    /* format time as `14 Jul 20:00:08`, and exactly 16 bytes */
    strftime(time_buf, sizeof(time_buf), "%d %b %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));

    nb_bytes = snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "%s", time_buf);

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsnprintf(msg + nb_bytes, MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    ....
}
```

The tricky things is when passing long parameters(make it longer than 32 bytes) and change `time_buf` to other value less than 32 (larger than 16, e.g., 31), these code will throw a stack smashing. After minutes debugging, I changed the `vsnprintf` calling line as

```
 vsnprintf(msg + nb_bytes, MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ - nb_bytes, fmt, ap);
```

and stack smashing gone, I think the problem fixed.

BUT: On `time_buf[32]`(or other larger size), why the **error calling**

```
 vsnprintf(msg + nb_bytes, MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ, fmt, ap);
```

not throw a stack smashing? More exactly, *why `msg`'s stack smashing related to that **unrelated** stack (`time_buf`) space?*

**UPDATE**: this is my `uname -a` output:

```
 Linux coanor 3.5.0-34-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 20:20:19 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char time_buf[32] = {0};
/* format time as `14 Jul 20:00:08`, and exactly 16 bytes */
strftime(time_buf, sizeof(time_buf), "%d %b %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));

nb_bytes = snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "%s", time_buf);
```

So effectively time_buf and msg contain the same data. `snprintf` returns the number of characters that would have been successfully written to msg not counting the null character.

```
vsnprintf(msg + nb_bytes, MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ, fmt, ap);
```

You are trying to write from the address given by `msg+nb_bytes`. You had 16 characters in msg. But you claim that you have `MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ` which is 32 characters. You are trying to write to end of the string. Perhaps fmt contains more than 15 characters.

```
vsnprintf(msg + nb_bytes, MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ - nb_bytes, fmt, ap);
```

This time you properly subtract the characters which have already been written to msg and give 16 characters to write to `vsnprintf`. It obeys and does not write beyond the end of the character array.

Comment: actually, you are mistaken. snprintf returns the number of characters that **would have been written**. Not the number of bytes successfully written. This mistake could lead to serious Troubles in this code. (Assume the resulting string would be larger than 32 and consider the next snprintf call with `MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ - nb_bytes`)

Comment: I guess they are the same here. OP is copying time_buf to msg.

Comment: It's likely that this is true for this specific case. But when I read your Statement, it seems to me as if this would always be the case which is not true. That's why I wanted to point out with my comment.

Comment: No issues. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using stack based buffers, you have to take care of not overrunning the allocated buffer. As you found out yourself, you introduced a possible buffer overflow using `vsnprintf(msg + nb_bytes, MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ, fmt, ap);`. This is, because you tell vsnprintf, there is more space available than there really is (because `nb_bytes = snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "%s", time_buf);` already wrote some bytes to the buffer).

Hence your fix, to pass `MAX_LOG_MSG_SZ - nb_bytes` instead of `MAX_LOG_MSG_SIZE`, is correct to avoid this effect.

It's also **important to know**, that snprintf and it's variants always return the number of Bytes that **would have been written**, regardless of the number of bytes actually written to the buffer.

EDIT: So in your case, you have to track the total length of the string during it's composition to make sure you don't overrun the total message buffer length.